# Unable to run rpy2 under Alpine Linux : no item called "package:utils" on the search list

Tags: r, dockerfile, rpy2

I am using alpine as base image in my dockerfile. And I am trying to install R and rpy2 in my dockerfile.
`RUN apk add R R-dev`
`pip3 install rpy2`

```
~ # python3 -m 'rpy2.tests'
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:186: RRuntimeWarning: Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/library/utils/libs/utils.so':
  Error relocating /usr/lib/R/library/utils/libs/utils.so: lzma_crc64: symbol not found

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:186: RRuntimeWarning: In addition: 
  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:186: RRuntimeWarning: Warning message:

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:186: RRuntimeWarning: package ‘utils’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:186: RRuntimeWarning: During startup - 
  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:186: RRuntimeWarning: package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
rpy2 version: 2.8.5
- built against R version: 3-3.3--72310
- running linked to R version: R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:186: RRuntimeWarning: Error in .Primitive("as.environment")("package:utils") : 
  no item called "package:utils" on the search list

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
E
======================================================================
ERROR: __main__ (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/tests.py", line 43, in load_tests
    suite_robjects = loader.discover('robjects', pattern, rpy_root)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 290, in discover
    __import__(start_dir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from rpy2.robjects.robject import RObjectMixin, RObject
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from rpy2.robjects.vectors import (BoolVector,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/vectors.py", line 31, in <module>
    utils_ri = rinterface.baseenv['as.environment'](rinterface.StrSexpVector(("package:utils", )))
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in .Primitive("as.environment")("package:utils") : 
  no item called "package:utils" on the search list


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: My base image is FROM python:3.7-alpine and rpy2 version is 2.9.2

Answer (score 0):

The first error is the root of the issue:

```
RRuntimeWarning: Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/library/utils/libs/utils.so'`
```

R was not compiled as a shared library.

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/vectors.py", line 32, in <module>
app_1    |     utils_ri = rinterface.baseenv['as.environment'](rinterface.StrSexpVector(("package:utils", )))
app_1    | rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in .Primitive("as.environment")("package:utils") : 
app_1    |   no item called "package:utils" on the search list